# How to fix "ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found" error in Python

Tags: python

My program must encode input messages using a Caesar Cipher. I tried to split my string to many letters by putting "/" between them. Then everything, in fact, worked(as I think). Eventually, when a message gets closer to chr(ord(ch)+ 2) an error pops out. How can I fix with this?

```
def main():

    print("This program will encode your messages using a Caesar Cipher")

    message = input("Enter the message: ")

    load = ("")

    codedMessage = ("")

    for i in message:

        load = load + i + "/"

        ''.join(load)

    for ch in load.split("/"):

        codedMessage = codedMessage + chr(ord(ch)+ 2)

    print("The coded message is:", codedMessage)

main()
```

Comment: `load = ''.join(load)`; the string `load` isn't modified in-place. (Indeed, it *cannot* be modified; `str` values are immutable.)

Comment: Inserting slashes and then splitting on that character is completely pointless; you can directly iterate over the characters via `for ch in message:`.  In fact, *you did exactly that*, in the process of generating the slashed string!

Comment: see [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for an easier way to translate strings.

Comment: What's the error that pops out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do this:

```
print("This program will encode your messages using a Caesar Cipher")

message = input("Enter the message: ")

codedMessage = ""

for ch in message:
    codedMessage = codedMessage + chr(ord(ch) + 2)


print("The coded message is:", codedMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `load` and splitting by '/'. You added extra characters only to split and remove them. Worse, in this case after you added `/` you are now left with a trailing `/` and so when you split(), the last part is a whitespace char.

So remove the first `for` loop adn cut to the next one directly. If you still see the issue then it could be that `input()` gives you trailing characters and so the error that you are seeing makes sense.

Simply run `input("The message").trimspace()` to remove trailing whitespace characters and the code should work. You could work on optimizing your code separately but the issue must be that.

Answer (score 0):

In your first `for` loop you always append a `/` character to the end of the string, meaning that you have a trailing `/` at the end of your final string. When you do a `load.split('/')` the string at the end gets split to the right, leaving you with an empty string at the end, which throws an error since you're trying to get the `ord` of nothing:

Here's a code example of what I'm talking about:

```
>>> "o/".split('/')
['o', '']
```

The last `''` is what is giving you the error. There are a bunch of ways you could go about fixing it, but I think skipping the `/` delimiters and just using the input string like a couple of other people are saying is probably your best bet.